# Azure Api Managment: How to change Repository?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We configured Azure Api Management and as part of it the Azure Repository where it should sync its configuration to.
Unfortunately we selected the wrong repository. Now we are unable to switch the Repository as any option for doing it is missing in the Api Management.
How to change the repository in Api Management?
Thanks for any advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a misunderstanding on my part. Everything works as described in the Microsoft documentation. I meant the repository of Apim is the one we have to set up in Git/Tfs, which is of course not so. Apim has its own repository and we can use for example powershell to read the data from that repository and upload it to our own repository or vice versa.